Experimental Design: Selecting value of $n$ given desired width of credible interval
Suppose I have $n$ IID Bernoulli trials with $k$ successes. Assume that as a prior we are assuming that $P(\theta)$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.
We can pretty easily use Bayes theorem to represent the posterior distribution here
$$
P(\theta|n,k)=\frac{\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\int_0^1\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}d\theta}
$$
However now suppose that we are going to build up an experiment to run to predict $\theta$ given this prior. What we would like to know is the answer to the following question

Question: What value of $n$ is necessary to guarantee that regardless of the value of $k$, the $95\%$ credible interval will have width of at most $.1$?

I think fundamentally I struggle to understand how we compute the credible intervals, which makes me unable to numerically come up with a good answer. If someone could show how you would answer this question I would appreciate the help and I would adjust the methodology myself in the event I want to change the width or $\alpha$

There is more than one type of credible interval, in particular the highest posterior density interval and the equal-tailed interval, though I doubt it makes much difference here.  I would expect the credible interval to be widest here when $k=\frac{n}2$ or $=\frac{n+1}2$ or  $=\frac{n-1}2$, depending on the parity of $n$.  So you can find the credible interval widths in these cases for different $n$ (easier with the equal-tailed interval) and choose the smallest $n$ for which this is less than $0.1$.

In this case, the posterior distribution is $Beta(k + 1, n - k + 1)$. Any posterior credible interval is thus formed by quantiles of the corresponding Beta distribution.
Lawrence et al. 2008 review possible approaches to computing Bayesian equivalents of power in this setup. The question you asked seems to correspond to what they call "WOC - worst outcome criterion" (assuming you want the highest density interval). They suggest the following approximate formula:
$$
n = \frac{z^2_{\alpha/2}}{l^2} - a - b
$$
Where $z_{\alpha/2}$ is quantile of the normal distribution, $\alpha$ is tail width ($0.05$ for 95% confidence interval), $l$ is the desired maximal interval width, $a, b$ are the parmaters of Beta prior on the proportion (in your case the prior is uniform and $a = b = 1$.
If exact answer is desired, the paper reviews possible approaches to compute it - it seems there is not simple closed form formula.
